# Oracle Apex - График не отображает данные при первом посещении страницы

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Я создал на Oracle Apex 4.2.6 несколько графиков,  в теле которых запросы выбирают данные исходя из значений в :P1_Date1 и :P1_Date2. Этим items я присвоил значения типа default.
[image: фрагмент из блока page item]
Обновление страницы (submit page) я определил для кнопки.

**Суть проблемы:** После логина в приложении, когда в первый раз открываешь страницу с графиками - на них пишется #no_data_message#, после нажатия кнопки - submit проходит и на графиках появляются данные.

**Цель:**  Исправить ошибку и сделать так, чтобы графики показывали данные по значениям items сразу.

Comment: Вам необходимо рассчитывать значение Item'a до загрузки страницы. Попробуйте создать Computations для этого Item'a, в Computations  выбрать Before Header

Comment: Или как вариант в запросе можно написать `nvl(:P1_DATE1, addmonths(sysdate, -2))`

Comment: И еще важное замечание. Обратите внимание, у вас написано `to_date(sysdate)`. Функция `to_date` принимает на вход строку, поэтому значение `sysdate` сначала будет преобразовано в строку, а потом обратно в дату. На этом месте вы можете словить очень трудновыявляемый баг, так что лучше исправьте сразу.

Comment: Dmitry - Фантастика! Работает! Моя проблема решена. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может, есть литература, где описаны подобные вопросы или Эл. ресурс? (для развития)

Comment: Подобные вопросы - это какие именно?

Comment: ss_beer - Вам тоже огромное спасибо! Ваш вариант также подошел! Может быть, со своей стороны посоветуете хороший источник с обьяснением подобны деталей?

Comment: @OleksiiLytvynenko, мы на работе приобрели книгу Oracle APEX. Рекомендации эксперта, там очень поверхностно все изложено, больше знаний из официальной доки можно почерпнуть, либо от коллег)

Comment: Dmitry  - к примеру, форматирование regions, classic & interactive reports, templates, fonts. Также было бы очень интересно более глубоко изучить те же computations, dynamic actions, processes

Comment: Увы, даже на английском книг почти нет. Могу порекомендовать htmlbook.ru для изучения основ CSS и HTML, а по апексу - читать блоги/форумы/SO. Отдельно порекомендую блог [Denes Kubicek](http://deneskubicek.blogspot.ru/) и его [демо-приложение](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:101:8322605659527:::::)